# How to share assets and global styles in Angular i18n app

Tags: angular, web, internationalization

I'm trying to use `@angular/localize` for i18n.

I found it is actually build completely separate bundles for each of the language.

Is there any way to make it share some common parts like assets (all static files), styles, favicon, probably some non-UI classes (services, guard, pipes etc) across all internationalized bundles?
Other words keep the whole stuff for my `i18n.sourceLocale` language at root folder and put only stuff where i18n actually differs under the lang subfolder?

Here are parts of my `angular.json`:

```json
"i18n": {
        "sourceLocale": "en-US",
        "locales": {
          "uk": "src/locale/messages.fr.json",
          "ru": "src/locale/messages.es.json"
        }
      },

"configurations": {
            "fr": {
              "localize": ["fr"],
              "baseHref": "/fr/",
              "outputPath": "dist/fr/"
            },
            "ru": {
              "localize": ["es"],
              "baseHref": "/es/",
              "outputPath": "dist/es/"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

during build, assets folder is copied to each language sensitive app
--> this solves your requirement "across all internationalized bundles" already

"and put only stuff where i18n actually differs under the lang subfolder"
--> this does not work, bcoz the stuff under the lang subfolder will be copied to the production web server. in other words: there is no higher level :-)

in order to reference stuff from assets, one must not use absolute paths in the img-src tag or css-url(), one need to remove the leading slash

html:

wrong: `src="/assets/my-image.png"`
correct: `scr="assets/my-image.png"`

styles.css:

wrong: `background-image: url(/assets/background.png);`
correct: `background-image: url(assets/background.png);`

see also here: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/38299

Comment: Too much text :-) Does it simply mean NO! it is impossible or you do not know the way how to prevent the content duplication?

Comment: inside angular no afaik, coz they do the copy (which is not a problem in my eyes). if you don't like the copy, u can use a cdn for static files